# Arduino Sensor Synchronization

Tags: arduino, sensor, raspberry-pi

I have the following 2 questions about using sensors (in general but I am mostly working with Arduino and Rpi)

1. Once a sensor is initialised or started, does it keep on throwing data continuously (which gets stored in buffer) or does it only respond once we ask it to using let's say

   my_sensor = S1.readline()

   In other words, when we start reading data from any sensor after turning it on (or lets say initialising it) and lets say we put 10 sec delay,
   how is the data read by the computer? I mean, will it read the data
   every 10 sec (and not care what happens in b/w those 9 sec)or will
   the data get stored even during those 10 Sec in the buffer and we
   get the latest value?
2. Suppose I have 3 sensors namely S1, S2 and S3 that send data at different rates lets say 50 Hz, 200 Hz and 500 Hz respectively. So
   how to synchronize the data in time? In other words, in 1 sec, S1
   would send 50 readings, but S3 will send 500 readings, so how can
   this difference in data sending rates be accounted for while doing
   calculations in Arduino / Rpi projects?.

Can someone make me understand the basics. I don't have background in embedded systems/ electronics. I am just a hobby electronics person.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. It depends on the sensor, some sensors you need to set a 'start' signal and you can get a response (like a ultrasonic distance sensor), but most sensors are 'stupid': whenever you read a signal, you get the signal at that moment (or a few ns/ms before because of some internal buffering for one complete 'result'). So if you need many values in a short time, you have to read the sensor more often and perform yourself an e.g. average calculation.
2. Normally sensors do not 'send' data. You request it from the sensor, so you decide the speed at which you receive the data. The more often you do, the better fluctuations you can anticipate on, but the more performance it takes.

Comment: Hi Michel, I once had a small project where I was reading some data from a radar and recording a video if the reading went above a threshold. But then I noticed that even after there was nothing infront of the radar, it was making the camera record the video which gave me the idea that may be the readings from the sensor are getting stored and even though there is nothing infront of it, this is happening due to some previous values that got stored. This made me think that may be the sensor is continuously spitting data and the computer is "catching" it.

Comment: It depends really on the sensor, some sensors are just sensors (without any real buffering), others are smart. I can imagine a radar is smarter, but I don't know about those. Btw, I'm also a hobby electronics person.